# Theta problems with Logistic Regressions

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

BRAND new to ML. Class project has us entering the code below.
First I am getting warning:

```
AttributeError: 'LogisticRegression' object has no attribute 'theta'.
```

If I define theta in the init segment, and add self.theta, that fixes that error, but then my model doesn't work.

```
def __init__(self, lr=0.01, num_iter=100000, fit_intercept=True, theta = 0, verbose=False):
        self.lr = lr
        self.num_iter = num_iter
        self.fit_intercept = fit_intercept
        self.theta = theta
```

Produces the following error:

```
model = LogisticRegression(lr=0.1, num_iter=300000)
preds = model.predict(X)
(preds == y).mean()
<ipython-input-198-c30787a24caa>:43: DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.
  (preds == y).mean()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-198-c30787a24caa>", line 43, in <module>
    (preds == y).mean()
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'mean'
```

Please see the code below (well-known code) and any tips are appreciated!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn import datasets

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, :2]
y = (iris.target != 0) * 1


# Logistic Regression Class for Sigmoid Func, Loss Func, and Gradient Descent
class LogisticRegression:
    def __init__(self, lr=0.01, num_iter=100000, fit_intercept=True, verbose=False):
        self.lr = lr
        self.num_iter = num_iter
        self.fit_intercept = fit_intercept
        self.verbose = verbose
    def __add_intercept(self, X):
        intercept = np.ones((X.shape[0], 1))
        return np.concatenate((intercept, X), axis=1)
    def __sigmoid(self, z):
        return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-z))
    def __loss(self, h, y):
        return (-y * np.log(h) - (1 - y) * np.log(1 - h)).mean()
    def fit(self, X, y):
        if self.fit_intercept:
            X = self.__add_intercept(X)
        self.theta = np.zeros(X.shape[1])

        for i in range(self.num_iter):
            z = np.dot(X, self.theta)
            h = self.__sigmoid(z)
            gradient = np.dot(X.T, (h - y)) / y.size
            self.theta -= self.lr * gradient
            
            if(self.verbose ==True and i % 10000 == 0):
                z = np.dot(X, self.theta)
                h = self.__sigmoid(z)
                print(f'loss: {self.__loss(h, y)} \t')


    def predict_prob(self, X):
        if self.fit_intercept:
            X = self.__add_intercept(X)
        return self.__sigmoid(np.dot(X, self.theta))
      
    def predict(self, X):
        return self.predict_prob(X).round()


model = LogisticRegression(lr=0.1, num_iter=300000)
preds = model.predict(X)
(preds == y).mean()

np.shape(preds)
np.shape(preds)
np.shape(y)
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.scatter(X[y == 0][:, 0], X[y == 0][:, 1], color='g', label='0')
plt.scatter(X[y == 1][:, 0], X[y == 1][:, 1], color='y', label='1')
plt.legend()
x1_min, x1_max = X[:,0].min(), X[:,0].max(),
x2_min, x2_max = X[:,1].min(), X[:,1].max(),
xx1, xx2 = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(x1_min, x1_max), np.linspace(x2_min, x2_max))
grid = np.c_[xx1.ravel(), xx2.ravel()]
probs = model.predict_prob(grid).reshape(xx1.shape)
plt.contour(xx1, xx2, probs, [0.5], linewidths=1, colors='red')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `self.theta` to be an array, not a scalar (at least in this specific problem).

In your case, (intercepted-augmented) `X` is a '3 by n' array, so try `self.theta = [0, 0, 0]` for example. This will correct the specific error `'bool' object has no attribute 'mean'`. Still, this will just produce preds as a zero vector; you haven't fit the model yet.

To let you know how I approached the error, I first went to the exact line the error message was pointing to, and put `print(preds == y)` before the line, and it printed out `False`. I guess what you expected was a *vector* of `True` and `False`s. Your `y` seemed okay; it was a vector (a `list` to be specific). So I tried `print(pred)`, which showed me a '3 by n' array, which *is* weird. Now going up from that line, I found out that `pred` comes from `predict_prob()`, especially `np.dot(X, self.theta)`. Here, when `X` is a '3 by n' array and `self.theta` is a scalar, numpy seems to multiply the scalar to each item in the array and return the array (having the same dimension as the original array), instead of doing *matrix multiplication*! So you need to explicitly provide `self.theta` as an array (conforming to the dimension of `X`).

Hope the answer and the reasoning behind it helped.

---

As for the red line you mentioned in the comment, I guess it is also because you are not fitting the model. (To see the problem, put `print(probs)` before `plt.countour(...)`. You'll see an array with 0.5 only.)

So try putting `model.fit(X, y)` before `preds = model.predict(X)`. (You'll also need to put `self.verbose = verbose` in the `__init__()`.)

After that, I get the following:

[image: Figure from the code]

Comment: You did it again! Hope I'm as readily capable as you one day, my friend. Thank you so much.